# Date and Time localization not works in Laravel-mix

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I have Laravel mix installed on my server. there is a chat part on website and I use some kind of class :

```
class ActivityCell extends Component {
    getTimestamp() {
        const {message} = this.props;
        return (
            <span className="font-weight-semi-bold">
                {utcDateCalendarTime(message.created_at)}
            </span>
        );
    }
```

And here is my `AppServiceProvider.php` file :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */

public function boot()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, Config::get('app.lc_all'));
    Carbon::setLocale(Config::get('app.locale'));
}
    public function register()
    {
        $this->registerPlugins();
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->bootDatabase();
        $this->bootResource();
    }

    /**
     * Boot database schema
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function bootDatabase()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }

    /**
     * Boot resource
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function bootResource()
    {
        Resource::withoutWrapping();
    }

    /**
     * Register plugins
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function registerPlugins()
    {
        $pluginDirs = File::directories(base_path('app/Plugins'));

        foreach ($pluginDirs as $pluginDir) {
            $class = "App\\Plugins\\" . basename($pluginDir) . "\\PluginServiceProvider";

            if (class_exists($class) && is_subclass_of($class, ServiceProvider::class)) {
                $this->app->register($class);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to put `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'tr');` on top of the class file but there is no success. Then tried to use carbon in order to make the date is viewed in different languages when I change the website language.

I added the following codes in `app/config.php` :

```
'locale' => env('APP_LOCALE', 'az'),
'lc_all' => env('APP_LC_ALL', 'az_AZ.UTF-8'),
```

and added following to the env file :

```
APP_LOCALE = az
APP_LC_ALL = az_AZ.UTF-8
```

in both methods, I was not successful. I am pretty sure that I am doing a mistake somewhere but can not find where exactly. Maybe I am missing to add something else to add. Any help would be highly appreciated.

EDIT : Adding Chat.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Events\ChatParticipationChanged;
use App\Events\ChatUpdated;
use App\Http\Resources\ChatMessage as ChatMessageResource;
use App\Http\Resources\MarketplaceTrade as MarketplaceTradeResource;
use ArrayObject;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use JSsVPSDioNXpfRC;
use DateTimeInterface;

class Chat extends Model
{
    protected $lastMessageAttribute;
    protected $lastMarketplaceTradeAttribute;

    /**
     * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * The event map for the model.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dispatchesEvents = [
        'updated' => ChatUpdated::class
    ];

    /**
     * Indicates if the IDs are auto-incrementing.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $incrementing = false;

    /**
     * Get the route key for the model.
     *
     * @return string
     */
protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
{
    return $date->translatedFormat('A B M');
}

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'id';
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function creator()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'creator_id', 'id');
    }

    /**
     * Participants for this chat
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function participants()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ChatParticipant::class, 'chat_id', 'id');
    }

    /**
     * Messages for this chat
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ChatMessage::class, 'chat_id', 'id');
    }

    /**
     * Update user's participation record
     *
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function updateParticipation($user)
    {
        $this->participants()->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->update(['last_read_at' => now()]);

        broadcast(new ChatParticipationChanged($this, $user));
    }

    /**
     * All marketplace trades hosted by this chat
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function marketplaceTrades()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(MarketplaceTrade::class, 'chat_id', 'id')
            ->has('buyer')->has('seller');
    }

    /**
     * @return Model|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany|mixed|object|null
     */
    public function getLatestMarketplaceTrade()
    {
        if (!isset($this->lastMarketplaceTradeAttribute)) {
            $trade = $this->marketplaceTrades()->latest()->first();

            $this->lastMarketplaceTradeAttribute = new MarketplaceTradeResource($trade);
        }
        return $this->lastMarketplaceTradeAttribute;
    }

    /**
     * Last chat message
     *
     * @return ChatMessageResource|ArrayObject|mixed
     */
    public function getLatestMessage()
    {
        if (!isset($this->lastMessageAttribute)) {
            $message = $this->messages()->latest()->first();

            if ($message) {
                $this->lastMessageAttribute = new ChatMessageResource($message);
            } else {
                $this->lastMessageAttribute = new ArrayObject();
            }
        }
        return $this->lastMessageAttribute;
    }

    /**
     * @param User $user
     * @return array
     */
    public function getParticipation($user)
    {
        $participant = $this->participants()
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)->without('user')
            ->first();

        $unreadMessagesCount = ($participant && $participant->last_read_at) ?
            $this->messages()->where('user_id', '!=', $user->id)
                ->where('created_at', '>', $participant->last_read_at)
                ->count() :
            $this->messages()->where('user_id', '!=', $user->id)
                ->count();

        return [
            'user_id'               => $user->id,
            'unread_messages_count' => $unreadMessagesCount
        ];
    }

    /**
     * If user should be allowed in this chat
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @return bool
     */
    public function shouldAllowUser($user)
    {
        $isParticipant = $this->participants()
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)->exists();
        return (
            $isParticipant ||
            $user->can('moderate_chats')
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function attachmentsDir()
    {
        return "chats/{$this->id}/message-attachments";
    }



}
```

Comment: You want to change default timezone?

Comment: Make sure you have run php artisan config:cache

Comment: I need to change the language of the date. It is in English by default but what I need is to change it to another language for example to Turkish. Website is in three different language and when I change to another language date not shows up in that selected language.

Comment: When I put this : `public function boot()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, Config::get('app.lc_all'));
    Carbon::setLocale(Config::get('app.locale'));
}`   I get http 500 error. I dont know why.

Comment: Can you check logs file what it saying?

Comment: `setlocale(LC_ALL, Config::get('app.lc_all'));` this config can not be found. this is what is said in error

Comment: Ok.
1. check what set on lc_all this index on config/app.php
2. make sure you have the locale file for intended language might be in /resources
    /lang/ folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on your namespace :

```
// Using PHP callable syntax
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Or,

```
// Using string syntax
\Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('ru');
```

You also need to use `translatedFormat()` method on your blade for use the translate format, like :

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::now()->translatedFormat('A B M') }} // утра 428 фев
```

You can use [serializeDate()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting) method on your model, to change timestamp column as a translated dataTime format :

```
use DateTimeInterface;

protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
{
    return $date->translatedFormat('A B M');
}
```

Comment: you mean adding the `use Carbon\Carbon;`  line in top of the AppServiceProvider file ?

Comment: Yes, or change `Carbon::setLocale(Config::get('app.locale'));` to `\Carbon\Carbon::setLocale(Config::get('app.locale'));`

Comment: I added this line : `{{ Carbon\Carbon::now()->translatedFormat('A B M') }} ` to my index.blade.php file which is located : `/home/user/public_html/resources/views/` then changed `\Carbon\Carbon::setLocale(Config::get('app.locale'));`  still not works. I get 500 error

Comment: I suggest you on your .env change `APP_DEBUG=true` and run `php artisan config:clear`  then let me know the error

Comment: did `APP_DEBUG=true` in env file but when I try to run the command `php artisan config:clear` I get an error after these changes. The error is like below :

`In AppServiceProvider.php line 20:

  Class 'App\Providers\Config' not found`

Line 20 is : `setlocale(LC_ALL, Config::get('app.lc_all'));`

Comment: add `use Config;` on the top

Comment: oh my God :) Laravel will kill me at the end.. Thank you very much it worked now. BUT how I should change my class file in order to show the date in different language? Because right now chat page still shows date in english , as it seems I need to use `{{ Carbon\Carbon::now()->translatedFormat('A B M') }}` in my classes ?

Comment: `{utcDateCalendarTime(message.created_at)}` - I need to use Carbon in this line, is there any possibility? I used : ` {{ `Carbon\Carbon::utcDateCalendarTime(message.created_at)->translatedFormat('A B M') }}`  but getting an error. this line is reposnible to show date in my chat page.

Comment: This is a js line I think, `{utcDateCalendarTime(message.created_at)}` you need to format your `created_at` column on back-end, may be its on your model

Comment: @MatinSuleymanli I added more on my answer , hope now `created_at`  column is serilized

Comment: thank you for edition in your answer. the case is that in my mode which file should I add this code block I am not sure. I mean `serializeDate` part.

Comment: You need to add it on your model

Comment: I added the codeblock you mentioned in my `Model -> /home/username/public_html/app/Models/Chat.php` . I edited my First post and added chat.php file after adding the code block please have a look. Itstill not works after adding this.

Comment: I edited your question and added the function on your model, let me know if you got it, i need to make a rollback

Comment: I have already added the function on my post. Function is added in the middle I think you missed it. After your addition there are double same function now.

Comment: tried with this edition not changes anything ? Should i run npm run prod ? I think it should reflect without compiling.

Comment: the problem is related with `created_at` column, how did you query? I think you made a db query

Comment: Yes it is from db query. [link](https://ibb.co/Lp2CCZ4) . please have a look image from database.

Comment: on eloquent/model query, the model method will apply. on db query it won't

Comment: But it is so  interesting then. there are some words like : "Last" , "Ago", "At" and etc.. in chat window where date is written. and where from they come then ? Check please [image](https://imgur.com/a/GTQRIxB)

Comment: i think your expected date format is `$date->translatedFormat('d M Y h:i A');`

Comment: What I found in : `/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Traits/Date.php` is so inteesting because all we need are here. All days , all words and etc. for example : `public function getCalendarFormats($locale = null){
        return [         'sameDay' => $this->getTranslationMessage('calendar.sameDay', $locale, '[Today at] LT'), 'nextDay' => $this->getTranslationMessage('calendar.nextDay', $locale, '[Tomorrow at] LT'),`  OR ` protected static $days = [// @call isDayOfWeek
        CarbonInterface::SUNDAY => 'Sunday',
        // @call isDayOfWeek
        CarbonInterface::MONDAY => 'Monday',`

Comment: So is there any way to translate these words where it has been written in date.php under carbon ?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, I'm afraid your question is very unformulated and incomplete as it is. The problem you are facing now is a different question and totally doesn't match the title. You can ask a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: you are right. Sorry about that. Thank you very much for your patience and support. I appreciate.